# Using Newtonsoft.Json inside Entity Framework DbContext, Type is not resolved for member exception

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework, json.net

In my `DbContext` class I've just added some reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` as I'm using it to store a serialized version of an entity for auditing.

Now when I'm running the `update-database` command I get the following in the console.

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
>   No pending explicit migrations.
>   Running Seed method.
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException,Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>
> Type is not resolved for member 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException,Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

All the reference's are just fine and the `Newtonsoft.Json` dll is in the output directory.

Does anyone know a way to get this working?

Thanks

Steve

EDIT:

```
public EFDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString = "DbConnectionString") : base(nameOrConnectionString)
{

     IObjectContextAdapter adapter = this;
     adapter.ObjectContext.SavingChanges += ObjectContextOnSavingChanges;

}

/// <summary>
/// Audits the records.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="objectContext">The object context.</param>
public void AuditRecords(ObjectContext objectContext)
{
    IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);
    foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
    {
        if (!stateEntryEntity.IsRelationship && stateEntryEntity.Entity != null && !(stateEntryEntity.Entity is AuditEntry))
        {
            AuditEntry audit = CreateAuditRecord(stateEntryEntity, objectContext);
            this.AuditEntries.Add(audit);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates the audit record.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="objectStateEntry">The object state entry.</param>
/// <param name="objectContext">The object context.</param>
/// <returns>AuditEntry.</returns>
public AuditEntry CreateAuditRecord(ObjectStateEntry objectStateEntry, ObjectContext objectContext)
{
    AuditEntry audit = new AuditEntry();

    audit.TableName = objectStateEntry.EntitySet.Name;
    audit.ApplicationUserId = UserId;

    if (objectStateEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {//entry is Added 
        audit.NewValue = GetEntryValueInString(objectStateEntry, false);
        audit.Action = AuditAction.Add;
    }
    else if (objectStateEntry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    {//entry in deleted
        audit.OldValue = GetEntryValueInString(objectStateEntry, true);
        audit.Action = AuditAction.Delete;
    }
    else
    {//entry is modified
        audit.OldValue = GetEntryValueInString(objectStateEntry, true);
        audit.NewValue = GetEntryValueInString(objectStateEntry, false);
        audit.Action = AuditAction.Update;

        IEnumerable<string> modifiedProperties = objectStateEntry.GetModifiedProperties();
        //assing collection of mismatched Columns name as serialized string 
        audit.ChangedColumns = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modifiedProperties.ToArray());
    }

    return audit;

}

/// <summary>
/// Clones the entity.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj">The object.</param>
/// <returns>EntityObject.</returns>
public object CloneEntity(BaseEntity obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), obj.GetType());
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the entry value in string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entry">The entry.</param>
/// <param name="isOrginal">if set to <c>true</c> [is orginal].</param>
/// <returns>System.String.</returns>
private string GetEntryValueInString(ObjectStateEntry entry, bool isOrginal)
{

    if (entry.Entity is BaseEntity)
    {
        object target = CloneEntity((BaseEntity)entry.Entity);
        foreach (string propName in entry.GetModifiedProperties())
        {
            object setterValue = null;
            if (isOrginal)
            {
                setterValue = entry.OriginalValues[propName];
            }
            else
            {
                setterValue = entry.CurrentValues[propName];
            }

            PropertyInfo propInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(propName);

            if (setterValue == DBNull.Value)
            {
                setterValue = null;
            }
            propInfo.SetValue(target, setterValue, null);
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So what is the update-database trying to do? Why do you run it if you only add a referenced library?

Comment: I've added some new migrations using add-migration, so running update-database to apply the migration. I have an event attached to SavingChanges which uses the Json.Net serializer

Comment: OK, you apparently use Json serialization in the Seed method, can you show that part?

Comment: I've edited my question and added the OnSavingChanges code. The seed method does insert some base data, then calls SaveChanges which will call invoke OnSavingChanges.

Comment: I think I've found the problem, just confirming and will post answer. Something slightly missleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a self referencing loop which caused the problem.

Some base data being inserted from the seed method. When I attach the debugger to the update-database process it actually gave me the correct exception. I wasn't aware you could attached a debugger before I googled it after posting this question.

Opened a second Visual Studio with the same project, put

```
if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

In the ctor and then was able to see the real exception. The

> 'Type is not resolved'

Message made me think it couldn't find the dll.

Thanks for your time [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold)

This question is pointless.